# H2 webserver failing on Jetty restart

Tags: jetty, restart, h2

We have our (new) build setup with the H2 web server starting up using the following Spring bean:

```
<bean id="org.h2.tools.Server-WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server"
    factory-method="createWebServer" depends-on="dataSource" init-method="start"
    lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webPort,8082" />
</bean>
```

This works fine for the other three developers (who all run a Mac or Linux), but poor me on my Windows laptop gets into trouble whenever Jetty restarts after finding a change in the code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.h2.tools.Server-WebServer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/controllers.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
Exception opening port "8082" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" [90061-154]
```

The theory is that the port is not properly released when Jetty signals the restart, and/or H2 doesn't re-use the port.

Now my question: How can I fix this? I figured it'd be a common problem, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your configuration it seems you are missing a destroy-method attribute. Try this:

```
<bean id="org.h2.tools.Server-WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server"
    factory-method="createWebServer" 
    depends-on="dataSource" 
    init-method="start" 
    destroy-method="stop" 
    lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webPort,8082" />
</bean>
```